# Artifacts on cheep HDMI 4k extender

Tags: hdmi, peripherals

I've acquired Chinese PW-HT239 HDMI extender which according to the description claims to support 4k resolution at 60 frames per second with 4:4:4 pixel format.

But when trying to configure it I noticed that fonts are blurred when on 3840x2160. Checking it more precisely with `lcdtest` I found out that vertical lines are blurred among 3 pixels and when moving them, they move by 2 pixel steps. (moving line by one real pixel causes the line on screen stay as is, moving by the next one makes it move)

**May it be reason that extender is a crap, or may it be something with my pc config?**

When connecting to the notebook via the displayport image is fine.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your cheap extender is cheap for a reason!

In my experience, this sort of thing is usually caused by cheap cables and the interference they pick up.

Comment: Wouldn't cable issue will rather cause total lack of image instead of compressing it vertically?

Comment: Easy way to test, can you get a clear picture when you connect an HDMI device without the extender? If so, the extender is to blame.

Comment: I've builded the mve setup, and verified both cables and extender. Cables are fine, artifacts only when on the extender.

Comment: How have you verified the extender? If cables work but the artifacts are seen when using the extender, I would definitely say that was to blame. You could try another ethernet cable just in case there is an issue with that